# Дискорд бот. Работает только одна команда

Tags: python, бот, discord

Делаю дискорд бота, нужно чтобы при написании !cat выдавалась рандом картинка кошки. Только когда запускаю, работает только эта команда, а остальные (!hi, !help) не работают. Код на python

```
import discord
import asyncio
import requests
import random
from discord.ext import commands

DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN = 'NTY5NDYwMDgyMTY1ODA5MTUz.XMSi8A.ZzeuHNushB0iACjou3QWP9iI8ek'

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
   author = message.author

   if message.content.startswith('!hi'):

       print('[command]: hi ')

       await message.channel.send("Привет "+ str(author)+" ты крутой!")



   if message.content.startswith('!help'):

       print('[command]: help ')

       await message.channel.send("Мои команды \n •!hi - Если ты еще сегодня не скем не здоровался,я сделаю это вместо твоих друзей.\n •(В разработке)")





  # if message.content.startswith('!'):

    #   print('[command]: milena ')

      # await message.channel.send("Она лох,наверное.")






class MyClient(discord.Client):


    async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        if message.content.startswith('!cat'):
            response = requests.get('https://aws.random.cat/meow')
            data = response.json()
            await message.channel.send(data['file'])
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

client = MyClient()

client.run(DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN)
```

Comment: Вы прописали команды для **первого** экземпляра `client = discord.Client()`. Но ниже по коду вы создаётся **второй** экземпляр `client = MyClient()` и тем самым просто уничтожаете старый экземпляр вместе со всеми командами в нём. А внутри MyClient у вас прописана одна-единственная команда !cat — вот только она очевидно и работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том что - после оператора **IF** вы делаете множество отступов потому и срабатывает только 1-я команда **print**, остальное для оператора **IF** неизвестно, убираем отступы и будет у вас всё работать.

```
import discord
import asyncio
import requests
import random
from discord.ext import commands

DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN = 'NTY5NDYwMDgyMTY1ODA5MTUz.XMSi8A.ZzeuHNushB0iACjou3QWP9iI8ek'

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    author = message.author

    if message.content.startswith('!hi'):
        print('[command]: hi ')
        await message.channel.send("Привет {user} ты крутой!".format(user=message.author.name))

    if message.content.startswith('!help'):         
       print('[command]: help ')    
       await message.channel.send("Мои команды \n •!hi - Если ты еще сегодня не скем не здоровался,я сделаю это вместо твоих друзей.\n •(В разработке)")   

  # if message.content.startswith('!'):

    #   print('[command]: milena ')

      # await message.channel.send("Она лох,наверное.")



class MyClient(discord.Client):


    async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        if message.content.startswith('!cat'):
            response = requests.get('https://aws.random.cat/meow')
            data = response.json()
            await message.channel.send(data['file'])
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

client = MyClient()

client.run(DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN)
```

Comment: у вас в `on_message` разные отступы. В питоне это вроде как критично

Comment: Я об этом и говорю. Можно делать отступы между операторами например для стилизации кода. Но делать отступы в самом операторе очень критично.

Comment: просто я думаю, может быть он границы функции тогда неправильно определит, потому что перед первой строкой 3 пробела, потом 4, а потом опять 3

Comment: в функции можно делать разное колличество отступов, не думаю что именно это повлияло на работоспособность кода. А вот отступы в операторе **IF** очень критично, с чем и столкнулся создатель темы. У него отработала операция вывода строки **print**  а остальное улетело в никуда.

Comment: "в функции можно делать разное колличество отступов" - извините, а вы пробовали запустить?

Comment: Вложенные инструкции объединяются в блоки по величине отступов. Отступ может быть любым, главное, чтобы в пределах одного вложенного блока отступ был одинаков. И про читаемость кода не забывайте. Отступ в 1 пробел, к примеру, не лучшее решение. Используйте 4 пробела (или знак табуляции, на худой конец). https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/sintaksis-yazyka-python.html . Возможно я погорячился насчет неограниченного колличества отступов в функции но у меня 1-2 не влияют на исполняемость кода. Больше не пробовал

Comment: @Ethernets Вам уже два раза написали, в on_message() разные отступы, ваш код не выполнится.